# HTTP get without waiting the response

Tags: java, http, get, response

My app connect to a server, and when I quit the app, I have to logout from server.

My problem is the response delay : my app doesn't quit enough quickly, I have to wait the response from the server before leaving in Handler.

The response is not important, I'm sure that if I send the get, it will logout.

***So, is it possible to logout (by http get) and close my app without waiting the response (but without stopping the "get process") ?***

Exactly like I do on computer with my browser : I click on logout button, then I close the browser, not waiting the welcome page from server...

I've tried by adding a short socket timeout, but the server doesn't logout.

Here is my method:

```
private void Disconnect() {

new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String errorMessage = null;
        Message msg = authHandler.obtainMessage();
        try {

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(LogoutURL);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                msg.what = AuthERR;
                authHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                return;
            }

            msg.what = AuthEND;
            msg.obj = choix;
            authHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            errorMessage = e.toString();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            errorMessage = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorMessage = e.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorMessage = e.toString();
        } finally {
            if (errorMessage != null) {
                Log.e("Logout", errorMessage);
                msg.what = AuthUnknownHostException;
                msg.obj = errorMessage;
                authHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}.start();
}
```

Comment: looks like java - but please add a suitable language tag whether it is or not.

Comment: Also, one obvious thing is that you're starting a new thread, and then presumably exiting straight afterwards. Most threading libraries I've encountered don't even guarantee that the thread *has* started by the time that the `start` function returns, only that the thread can run in the future.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is half duplex request-response protocol. Until you get the response, you have no proof that the request made it to the server.  It could get lost due to a network problem.

Answer (score 2):

How do you know the server has received the logout request if you quit the application immediately? I suggest to change the server to send response immediately then finish logout in the background, so your client will have a quick response.

Comment: So what about @Damin_The_Unbeliever 's comment, that the thread might not have started when you quit. Have you tried doing the logout on the main thread and see if it is to slow for you? What exactly means "my app doesn't quit enough quickly"? How many ms?

Answer (score 0):

If the library does not provide a way to abandon a connection, you can simply exit.

```
Thread logoutThread = new LogoutThread();
logoutThread().start();
logoutThread.join(1000);
System.exit(0);
```

Suppose, empirically, 1 second is good enough in most cases. Of course there's the risk of not delivering the logout request to server, but that's always to be expected in network applications.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea, I'm going to try it. I tried something similar by adding a timeout to the socket, but with a too short timeout, so I will try a little bit more (1 second looks good).